# Convert JOOQ results to a Map

Tags: json, scala, jooq, scalatra

I am developing a Web API using Scala with Scalatra and JOOQ. I would like to deal with Maps instead of Records, Case Classes etc

Using JacksonJsonSupport to automatically serialize my data to JSON :

```
get("/test") {

    val r = DBManager.query select(MODULE.ID, MODULO.NAME) from MODULE fetchArrays

    Map("result" -> r)
}
```

hitting 0.0.0.0:8080/test produces the following output:

```
{"result":[[1,"VelanRT"],[2,"GeobodyMorphologicalConvolution"], [3,"Sismofacies"]}
```

but, if using `fetchMaps` instead of `fetchArrays` :

```
{"result":[{},{},{}]}
```

what I expected is a `Map[String, AnyVal]`, with the column name as the key and the value being the DB tuple value

Is there any additional setup I need to do? I there a chance that the json serialization from `JacksonSupport` is messing with things?

Comment: What does a simple `toString()` call on the result of `fetchMaps()` yield?

Comment: Very strange behavior, the toString() yields the maps just fine, and if I return the `List[Result]` *JacksonSupport* serializes everything normally .. but if I nest it inside a map I get this `{}` strange behavior

Comment: I think this is due a type mismatch between the Java List and the Scala List

Comment: Is there a way to use JOOQ with Scala Immutable datastructures?

Comment: You could wrap the data structures using implicit type conversion...